# How to finish setup of dvd::rip?

Tags: 11.04, dvd, cd-ripping

I had isntalled dvd:rip and trying to finish setup, but while checking dependencies I found out that missed rar, and it's necessary to install old version (min 2.71 and max 2.99). 
By default I could install only 4.0 version through Software center(or Synaptic).

Could somebody help me to find and install rar version 2.xx ?
thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here you can see "Dependency check" image  below.

[image: Dependency check]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go through the documentation on the dvd::rip site you'll be able to find the package there itself and instructions as well.

[SOURCE](http://www.exit1.org/dvdrip/doc/install.cipp#inst_rar):

> ***1.3.4 rar (for vobsub compression):***
>
> Some special notes about the rar program. MPlayer supports vobsub
>   files compressed with rar, but you need a 2.x version, 3.x and higher
>   doesn't work. You can get a 2.x version locally from here:
>
> http://www.exit1.org/dvdrip/contrib/rarlnx271.sfx.bin
>
> I suggest to install the binary to e.g. /usr/local/bin. Then configure
>   this path using the Preferences dialog.

**EDIT:**

1. First you need to open terminal and copy the file from its location to `/usr/local/bin`.
2. Then make the file executable
3. Run the file.

Example : (if the file got downloaded in my Downloads directory)

```
cp ~/Downloads/rarlnx271.sfx.bin /usr/local/bin/      #copies the file 
cd /usr/local/bin/                                    #changes working directory
chmod +x rarlnx271.sfx.bin                            #makes file executable
./rarlnx271.sfx.bin                                   #runs the file
```

Comment: Yes, I had downloaded binary rarlnx271.sfx.bin , but how to install it ? :) That's the problem for me. If you could give me some more details how to do that, that's would be great

Comment: edited the answer.

Comment: Your suggestion in respect of installing binary was very helpful. I had successfully installed binary into /usr/local/bin/, and now "dependency check" looks OK, but ripping process freezes on the first step - I had edited my question and added some images.

Comment: I had go through dvd:rip documentation attentively and make some changes in the preferences, now everything works fine. Thanks for your support

Answer (score 2):

Are you installing from source?  Or perhaps from a PPA?  There's no need.  It's usually simpler and safer to use packaged versions when they are available.

dvd::rip is available in the multiverse repository (version 0.98.11) for 11.04 (anything after 10.04 actually).

According to the source package, rar is a "suggested package" not a "depends" or "recommends".  If you use the pre-packaged multiverse version you should have no problems.

From what I can tell, there's really no reason not to.  The current upstream version is 0.98.11 and that's the same version in 11.04's multiverse repository.  Just enable multiverse and:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install dvdrip`

Comment: Actually I had installed dvd:rip from Software center and has got a note that old version (min 2.71 and max 2.99) is necessary to be installed. OK, I'll try your suggestions in respect of multiverse version of dvd:rip and keep you informed

Comment: I had checked - multiverse repository was enabled before and dvd:rip was installed from pre-packeged version, I added some images to the question - the version is 0.98.11 as you had mentioned, but anyway Dependency Check shows rar issue. I had isntalled binary rar2.71 as requested by the programm and now it looks OK, but I can't rip my 1st DVD anyway - the process freezes :(